# Remove Visual Studio infinite whitespace

Tags: visual-studio, windows-10

I just got Windows 10 and it is my preference to not have unlimited whitespaces in my Visual Studio code pane. Is there a way to turn this off?

Comment: Are you referring to the "virtual space" setting?

Comment: Yes i found how to turn it off and I think that did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out to me in the comments, the setting I was refering to was **virtual space**. To turn it off I used `ctrl + Q` and searched "virtual space". There is a little check box to disable it.